# How do I sort the following list

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, lambda

I have a list called clusters and in that list there is another list called tags which has a sequenceno.

How do I sort clusters by using the max of seuqenceno from tags of each cluster using lambda expression in one line.

Something like

```
clusters.Sort((a,b) => a.tags......
```

Comment: Is this "in one line" some kind of business requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A not very efficient solution (computes O(N log N) maximums, but runs in-place):

```
clusters.Sort((a,b) => a.tags.Max(x => x.sequenceno)
                        .CompareTo(b.tags.Max(x => x.sequenceno)));
```

A somewhat better solution (only computes O(N) maximums, but does not work in-place):

```
var max = clusters.ConvertAll(c => c.tags.Max(x => x.sequenceno);
clusters = clusters.Select((x,i) => new{x,i})
                   .OrderBy(xi => max[xi.i].CompareTo(max[xi.j]))
                   .Select(xi => xi.x)
                   .ToList();
```

It will be difficult to do this sort efficiently in-place without either:

1. Adding a property to the cluster class to cache the maximum sequence number of the tags (and handle its possible invalidation, which can get tricky);
2. Adding a property to the cluster class to keep track of its index (which may not make sense in there, and may raise invalidation issues as well);
3. Using a list of wrappers around clusters that keep track of any of the values mentioned in 1 and 2;
4. Rolling your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: True, but before optimizing, ensure there actually is a performance problem... If the tag lists are not too large I would not bother.

Comment: The in-place solution works great because the validation issues are already taken care of. Also The tag lists are quite small. Thanks!

Comment: @jeroenh: Exactly. I mentioned specifically what was the inefficient part, and how inefficient it was so that making a decision will be easier.

Answer (score 3):

using LINQ OrderBy:

```
 var orderedClusters = clusters.OrderBy(list => list.Max(item => item.SequenceNo))
```